LINE Messaging APIのレート制限回避方法について
200人ほどのグループに公式ラインアカウントのLINE Messaging APIを使用して時間指定でメッセージを送信しようとしています。しかし、以下のようなエラーが発生します。
エラー: 429 Too Many Requests
以下の2つの方法で実装を試みましたが、少人数では成功するものの、大人数では失敗します。
Google Apps Script (GAS)を用いた方法
ESP32でHTTP POSTリクエストを送信する方法
それぞれのサンプルコードを以下に示します（アクセストークン等の情報はマスク済みです）。レート制限を回避する方法、または代替案についてご教示いただけると助かります。
エラーメッセージ
https://developers.line.biz/ja/docs/messaging-api/development-guidelines/#:~:text=%23-,LINE%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E9%87%8F%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E7%A6%81%E6%AD%A2,%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%80%81429%20Too%20Many%20Requests%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82,-%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90%E5%86%85
GAS
const LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN = "******"; // LINEチャネルアクセストークンをここに設定

function doPost(e) {
  const events = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events;

  events.forEach(event => {
    const replyToken = event.replyToken;
    const messageText = event.message.text;
    const groupId = event.source.groupId || "なし";
    const roomId = event.source.roomId || "なし";

    // "ID"が含まれている場合に返信
    if (messageText && messageText.toLowerCase().includes("id")) {
      const replyMessage = `グループID: ${groupId}\nルームID: ${roomId}`;
      replyToLine(replyToken, replyMessage);
    }
  });

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function replyToLine(replyToken, message) {
  const url = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply";
  const payload = {
    replyToken: replyToken,
    messages: [{
      type: "text",
      text: message,
    }],
  };

  const options = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}

// LINE APIでメッセージを送信
function sendLineMessage(groupId, message) {
  const url = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push";
  const payload = {
    to: groupId,
    messages: [{
      type: "text",
      text: message,
    }],
  };

  const options = {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

// スケジュールに基づいてメッセージを送信
function sendScheduledMessages() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Schedule"); // スケジュールを記録したシート名
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  const now = new Date();

  data.forEach((row, index) => {
    if (index === 0) return; // ヘッダーをスキップ
    const [datetime, groupId, message, sentFlag] = row;

    if (!sentFlag && datetime instanceof Date && datetime <= now) {
      sendLineMessage(groupId, message);

      // メッセージ送信済みフラグを更新
      sheet.getRange(index + 1, 4).setValue(true); // 「送信済みフラグ」が4列目の場合
    }
  });
}
// トリガーを設定
function createTimeTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendScheduledMessages")
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1) // 1分おきにチェック
    .create();
}

ESP32
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// WiFi設定
const char* ssid = "****";
const char* password = "****";

// LINE Messaging API設定
const char* lineToken = "****";
const char* lineEndpoint = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push";
const char* groupId = "****"; 

// NTP設定
const char* ntpServer = "ntp.nict.jp";
const long gmtOffset_sec = 32400;  // 日本時間 (UTC+9)
const int daylightOffset_sec = 0;

// メッセージ構造体
struct ScheduledMessage {
    time_t scheduledTime;
    String message;
};

// スケジュールされたメッセージのリスト
std::vector<ScheduledMessage> messages = {
    // 2024年12月
    {1734777000, String("テスト配信です。") }
};

void printLocalTime() {
    struct tm timeinfo;
    if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
        Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
        return;
    }
    Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
}

// Helper function to escape JSON string
String escapeJSON(const String& input) {
    String output = "";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case '"': output += "\\\""; break;
            case '\\': output += "\\\\"; break;
            case '\b': output += "\\b"; break;
            case '\f': output += "\\f"; break;
            case '\n': output += "\\n"; break;
            case '\r': output += "\\r"; break;
            case '\t': output += "\\t"; break;
            default:
                if (c < 0x20) {
                    char hex[7];
                    snprintf(hex, 7, "\\u%04x", c);
                    output += hex;
                } else {
                    output += c;
                }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

void sendLineMessage(const String& message) {
    Serial.println("Attempting to send LINE message...");
    
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        HTTPClient http;
        Serial.println("Starting HTTP connection...");
        http.begin(lineEndpoint);
        
        // ヘッダー設定
        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        http.addHeader("Authorization", String("Bearer ") + lineToken);
        
        // メッセージ本文の作成 (JSONエスケープを適用)
        String escapedMessage = escapeJSON(message);
        String jsonMessage = "{\"to\":\"" + String(groupId) + "\",\"messages\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"" + escapedMessage + "\"}]}";
        Serial.println("JSON Message: " + jsonMessage);
        
        // POST要求の送信
        Serial.println("Sending POST request...");
        int httpCode = http.POST(jsonMessage);
        Serial.printf("HTTP Response code: %d\n", httpCode);
        
        if (httpCode > 0) {
            String response = http.getString();
            Serial.println("HTTP Response: " + response);
        } else {
            Serial.printf("Error sending message: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
        }
        
        http.end();
    } else {
        Serial.println("WiFi not connected!");
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Starting setup...");
    
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("\nWiFi connected");
    Serial.printf("IP address: %s\n", WiFi.localIP().toString().c_str());
    
    configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
    Serial.println("Current time: ");
    printLocalTime();
}

void checkSchedule() {
    Serial.println("\n--- Checking Schedule ---");
    struct tm timeinfo;
    if (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
        return;
    }
    
    time_t now = time(nullptr);
    Serial.printf("Current time: %ld\n", now);
    printLocalTime();
    
    for (const auto& scheduledMessage : messages) {
        Serial.printf("Checking message scheduled for: %ld (in %ld seconds)\n", 
                     scheduledMessage.scheduledTime, 
                     scheduledMessage.scheduledTime - now);
                     
        if (now >= scheduledMessage.scheduledTime && now < scheduledMessage.scheduledTime + 60) {
            Serial.println("Time match found! Sending message...");
            sendLineMessage(scheduledMessage.message);
            delay(1000); // レート制限を避けるため
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    checkSchedule();
    delay(60000); // 60秒ごとにチェック
}


友だち登録されているすべてのユーザーに対して送信する「ブロードキャストメッセージ」というものがあるようです。
ブロードキャストメッセージを送る

LINE公式アカウントと友だちになっているすべてのユーザーに、任意のタイミングでメッセージを送信します。


返信ありがとうございます。
試してみましたが、グループではなく個人のチャットにメッセージが送られてしまうため厳しいです。
